# LTspice peak detector analysis: Time step too small

Tags: transistors, amplifier, diodes, ltspice, sample-and-hold

I made a peak detector with a test file in LTspice.

Here is the diagram:

[image: Diagram]

When running the test file, I ran into this an error message:

> Time step too small; time = 0.011, timestep = 1.26068e-017: trouble with node "x1:n001"

Node n001 is the output node of the amplifier in the peak detector. I think the solution is to give some parameter to specify the diode but I don't know what those parameters should be.

Code for the peak detector:

```
    Version 4
    SHEET 1 880 680
    WIRE 16 112 -48 112
    WIRE 176 128 112 128
    WIRE 16 144 -48 144
    WIRE 176 160 176 128
    WIRE -48 256 -48 144
    WIRE 80 256 -48 256
    WIRE 176 256 176 224
    WIRE 176 256 80 256
    WIRE 272 256 176 256
    WIRE 176 272 176 256
    WIRE 80 288 80 256
    WIRE 80 304 80 288
    WIRE 32 368 -48 368
    WIRE 176 384 176 336
    WIRE 176 384 80 384
    WIRE 176 400 176 384
    FLAG 176 400 0
    FLAG -48 112 In_Peak_Detect
    IOPIN -48 112 In
    FLAG 272 256 Out_Peak_Detect
    IOPIN 272 256 Out
    FLAG -48 368 Ctrl_Peak_Detect
    IOPIN -48 368 In
    SYMBOL Ideal_OP_Amp 80 128 R0
    SYMATTR InstName X1
    SYMBOL diode 160 160 R0
    SYMATTR InstName D1
    SYMBOL cap 160 272 R0
    SYMATTR InstName C1
    SYMATTR Value 10
    SYMBOL nmos 32 288 R0
    SYMATTR InstName M1
    SYMATTR Value NMOSx
    TEXT 208 80 Left 2 !.model NMOSx nmos kp=40 L=100U W=100U Vt0=0.15 lambda=0.01
```

Code for the test file:

```
     Version 4
    SHEET 1 880 680
    WIRE 112 80 -112 80
    WIRE 352 128 272 128
    WIRE 352 144 352 128
    WIRE -192 160 -192 80
    WIRE -128 160 -192 160
    WIRE 112 160 -128 160
    WIRE -128 224 -128 160
    WIRE 352 224 -128 224
    WIRE -128 240 -128 224
    FLAG -128 240 0
    SYMBOL Peak_Detector 192 128 R0
    SYMATTR InstName X1
    SYMBOL voltage -96 80 R90
    WINDOW 0 -32 56 VBottom 2
    WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
    WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
    WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
    SYMATTR InstName V1
    SYMATTR Value PWL(0 1 10ms 1 10.01ms 1.4 20ms 1.4 20.01ms 0.5 30ms 0.5)
    SYMBOL res 336 128 R0
    SYMATTR InstName R1
    SYMATTR Value 1
```

Comment: Try adding a 0.1 ohm resistor in series with the op-amp output. Report back.

Comment: I added the 0.1 ohm resistor in the Peak-detector model. The previous problem didn't show up. Instead, it runs into a very slow simulation process. The simulation speed is as slow as 757ps/s.

Comment: Keep messing with it to something works right for you. Sims can be obstinate sometimes especially LTVice.

Comment: I find two things: 1. the simulation runs fast and quick without the diode. 2. Trying different values of resistance doesn't seem to help the situation. Neither does changing the parameter of capacitor or nmos help. Do you know what can I do with the diode such as changing the param to speed up the simualtion?

Comment: Change the diode. Just keep plugging away at it. You'll get a better feel/grasp as you keep trying things. Try a 1N4148 diode.

Comment: I tried 1N4148 with different resistance values. They don't work. However, I find a a group of parameter ".model D D Vfwd=0.7 Vrev=1k Ron=0.1 Roff=10Meg epsilon=100m revepsilon=50m" and now program runs. However, I run into new problem: the output voltage of peak detector drops to -1.325V as PWL input goes from 1.4V to 0.5V.  capcitor capacitance is 1. If capacitance is 2 or 3, "time-step too small" error occurs. I am fine with capcitance 1. But still struggle with why the output voltage of peak detector is negative. Maybe the diode is not isolating. What param should I change in this case?

Comment: Josh, take note that this is a Q and A site and not an on-line training facility. These are not my rules.

Comment: Get it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Josh Your schematics can't be run because you're using custom symbols that you do not provide (for opamp and the hierarchical schematic); you're also lacking a valid simulation card (I guess `.TRAN` is what you want). Suppose one can get around those problems, your circuit doesn't make sense: you are using the control pin tied to ground, and a load of 1 Ohm which goes directly across the 10 Farad (!!!) cap which is used by the peak detector. I suggest revisiting your choices, because the schematic doesn't make sense, not even from a testing point of view.